# How do I define the limits and solve this double integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

$$\iint_{\Omega xy}(x + 1)(x^2 − y) \, dx \, dy
$$

where region $\Omega xy$ defined by 
$$6 − 2x ≤ y ≤ 10 − 2x \\x^2 ≤ y ≤ x^2 + 4$$

Comment: What are you thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is begging for a change of variables.  The second set of bounding curves can be written $x^2-y =0$ and $x^2-y=4$.  So probably let $u=x^2-y$ so that the limits for $u$ are constant and the factor in the integrand becomes just $u$.

Then let $v = 2x+y$ which causes the limits for $v$ to be constant also.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think I kinda figured it out after seeing this

Comment: @needynerd Note that $\Omega$ consists of two regions $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ and $(u, v) = (x^2 - y, 2 x + y)$ maps each of them to $[-4, 0] \times [6, 10]$. We can avoid finding the two inverse maps separately by considering the inverse Jacobian:
$$J = \left| \det \frac {\partial(u, v)} {\partial(x, y)} \right| = 2 |x + 1|, \\
(x + 1) (x^2 - y) J^{-1} = \frac u 2 \operatorname {sgn}(x + 1).$$
Observe that $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ lie on the opposite sides of the line $x = -1$.